# Could creation of various image sizes cause slow form submission response?

Tags: images, uploads, media-library

when I submit an image to WP media gallery or trough various plugins, the process takes quite some time to complete.

A 4MB image takes like 2-5 seconds to upload (got fast connection), then there is like 20 seconds processing before the process complets. So if I upload several images i reach minutes of waiting territory which is quite annoying.

I noticed for each image 12 size variations are created: 3 WP defaults, 5 from the SELA theme, and I don't know from where the others are ordered. Is this the cause of the problem? Would removing image size creation help?

Comment: Connections tend to be assymetrical, and even if you have 1Gbit pipe to your house that doesn't meant the route to the server can support that. Adding more image sizes can slow things down, but that's speculation. Have you profiled the upload process to see exactly what the timings are for upload vs processing? And have you profiled server side to see what the actual timings are for the page generation?

Comment: I've seen this in the past with either Salient or Niven as a theme, a single upload of a modestly sized image took quite a bit longer than I've come to expect and it appears to have been because the theme generated a dozen different sizes for each upload.  Once the theme was removed upload times drastically decreased.  There are a couple of image compression plugins, like WP Smush, that reduce file size and they also slow the process, but it's a fair tradeoff for the size reduction in your image files.